# Android - Google spreadsheet - upload

Tags: android, android-studio, upload, google-sheets

I spend last 3 days trying to find solution to this problem. I just want to ask for help. Do someone know about some good tutorial on how to upload to google spreadsheet whole table?

I have already figured out how to download table. ([Tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/google-spreadsheet-as-data-source-android), [GitHub Project](https://github.com/telerik/Android-samples/tree/master/Blogs/Json-Reader) )
And I'm just looking for something like this, but for upload...
Can someone please help me?